# Gallery based on SharePoint List Selected

Tags: powerapps

I have multiple lists (5) with the same data structure/column representing different country information. The country name is the name of the List.

I am using IF statements to patch data to the respective lists depending on the country selected in the dropdown.

Now I want to make a gallery page to view and edit submitted records based on the country selected using a dropdown. I want each gallery to load for editing based on the country selected.

What is the best way to go about it?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using either of below options:

1. Recommended if all lists have exact same column names & column types: Add one gallery control in your Power app and set `items` property of gallery control to something like this:

   ```
   Switch(
       Dropdown1.Selected.Value,
       "India",
       India,
       "Australia",
       Australia,
       "Germany",
       Germany
   )
   ```
2. In other cases: Add 5 gallery controls in your Power App. Set `items` property of each gallery control to respective SharePoint list and `Visible` property of gallery control based on drop down values like given below:

   **For example**: For SharePoint list named "India", set `items` property to `India` and set `Visible` property to `Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "India"`. Similarly you can set items and Visible to other gallery controls respectively based on SharePoint list names.